# How can I cut something on equations?

Tags: equations

How can I cut the eighteens in the equation like that on the image? What if I also wanted to add a note on the equivalent sign.

[image]

Comment: Use the `cancel` package: https://ctan.org/pkg/cancel

Answer (score 2):

As Óscar says, you can use the [cancel package](https://ctan.org/pkg/cancel?lang=en) to cross out the numbers, e.g. write `\cancel{18}`. One way to add a note on the equivalence, modified from the [AMS-LaTeX documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath?lang=en) (pp.7-8), is to use the `align` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        & \Pr\left[Z_{1-\alpha}>\frac{18+\frac{10}{7}-\bar{x}}{\sigma}\right] && \\ 
        \iff  &  \Pr\left[Z_{1-\alpha}>\frac{\cancel{18}+\frac{10}{7}-\cancel{18}}{1.14455}\right] && \text{Explanation}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]